# Android: implementing contacts app layout

Tags: android, layout

Does anyone have a tutorial or link to android source or anything that I can use to learn how android created their contacts app.  I'm looking into creating a small app that will can display some data similar to how the contacts app displays its contacts.  It seems to be some kind of list view with image buttons for actions.

**EDIT*****
Lets make this a little easier, any one have any idea how on Android 2.1 and so far up to 2.3 the contacts tab and favorites tab can display a contact and next to it a button.  I had thought this was somehow done in a listview but according to what I've read it's not possible to have a clickable listview plus button on a list item.  So I'm assuming somehow a listview is being created and a button added next to the listview.  I've tried looking at stock android source on github but I just dont understand it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the git hub for the Android contacts application:
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts

Comment: dang this is more completed then I thought.  I have no where near the necessary knowledge to understand how the contacts app is written.  Thank you for the link IncrediApp.  Hopefully there's a tutorial out there (havent found one yet) that can break this down for me.